How can QUIC/HTTP3 be faster using UDP?
QUIC states that it is uses UDP instead of TCP due to loading page performance reasons.
Knowing that UDP has no "ACK" functionality built in, I am assuming that they are implementing timeouts while waiting for packets, since you could miss UDP packets without noticing it.
How can implementing timeouts be faster than using TCP?

QUIC doesn't "use UDP" instead of TCP – that's often repeated but is far too much a "by the letter" interpretation of the 'OSI layer' cake.
It would be more accurate to say that QUIC itself is instead of TCP, as it implements all of the necessary features of a transport protocol – ACKs and retransmission, flow control, congestion control, etc. – whereas the UDP layer is merely for port multiplexing and doesn't actually occupy the "transport protocol" slot.
(For most purposes, you can treat "X over UDP" the same way as "X over raw IP", as both provide the exact same 'raw datagram' service over which a reliable transport can be implemented; indeed SCTP is a transport protocol commonly used over either UDP or raw IP.
Therefore, if TCP can implement ACKs on top of IP which doesn't have them, then QUIC or μTP or RTP can equally well implement ACKs over UDP which doesn't have them.)

To a first approximation, you can think of QUIC as "TCP (and HTTP) reimplemented over UDP".
This allows apps to bring their own "TCP" implementation instead of being forced to work with whatever TCP implementation the host OS provides.
This is why Google developed QUIC; so that Google's apps like Chrome, Google Maps, YouTube, and others could all have a reliable Google-controlled implementation of their "HTTP" transport instead of having to deal with different feature sets and different bugs with different TCP stacks in Windows, macOS, iOS, various Linux distros, etc.
It also allows Google's apps and other QUIC-using apps to use modernizations that maybe aren't available on every OS's TCP stack yet. So for example you can do low-latency 0-RTT things with QUIC that you can't do on TCP stacks that don't support TCP Fast Open (TFO) yet. Or you can use a more suitable congestion control algorithm than the host OS's TCP stack supports yet. Or perhaps you can support multipath flows even if your host OS's TCP stack doesn't support Multipath TCP (MPTCP) yet.
So QUIC isn't necessarily faster than a proper modern TCP stack; it's basically the same thing, just implemented in code that's part of the app, so the app developer isn't stuck using the TCP code supplied by the OS's network stack.

This is good information to read, thanks.

That's a great explanation, thanks! I always kinda wondered why they'd bother.
